# R/Python Webscraping - Date issue 1970

Tags: python, r, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, rvest

I am trying to web scrape the website fairygodboss.com and having trouble retrieving the reviews date... When I run the following under the `rvest` package:

```
url<-read_html('https://fairygodboss.com/company-reviews/boston-consulting-group')
Review<-url %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath ='//p[@class="textColor6 w-700 p-b-10"]')%>%
  html_text()
```

I should get the different dates as 2017/2016, but instead I get all dated as January 1970.

Please can you help me identify the issue.

I also tried on Python with bs4 as follows, I still have 1970 everywhere:

```
import urllib
r = urllib.urlopen('https://fairygodboss.com/company-reviews/boston-consulting-group').read()
```

Comment: Scraping this site is against the Terms and Conditions.

Comment: I am doing it for academic and learning purpose, non commercial use of it.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use the package `Selenium`

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get the dates of the review with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://fairygodboss.com/company-reviews/boston-consulting-group'
shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

list_Text_Review <- list()

for(i in 1 : 5)
{
  full_Xpath <- paste0('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[', i, ']/div[1]/div[2]')
  web_Obj_Review <- remDr$findElement("xpath", full_Xpath)
  list_Text_Review[[i]] <- web_Obj_Review$getElementText()[[1]]
}

unlist(list_Text_Review)

[1] "Anonymous shared this review of Boston Consulting Group, United States on Mar 20th, 2022"
[2] "Anonymous shared this review of Boston Consulting Group, United Kingdom on Mar 9th, 2022"
[3] "Anonymous shared this review of Boston Consulting Group, United States on May 18th, 2021"
[4] "Anonymous shared this review of Boston Consulting Group, United States on May 17th, 2021"
[5] "Anonymous shared this review of Boston Consulting Group, United States on Apr 9th, 2021"
```